# Substitute for having an optional recursive type in struct

Tags: swift, struct, types

I need to make a struct in Swift. Here is what it should look like:

```
struct PostType: Hashable, Codable {
    let _id: String
    let content: String
    let time: Int
    let comments: Int
    let loves: Int
    let reposts: Int
    let poster: Poster
    let revisions: [Revision]
    let edited: Optional<Int>
    let repost: Optional<PostType>
}
```

This does not work, obviously, as Swift doesn't allow a recursive type (`let repost: Optional<PostType>`). But I need some way of doing this, as it is critical to my app.
Whatever the solution is, it must 1. allow JSON to be decoded into it 2. be codable 3. `repost` must be optional

Any help would be much appreciated. I simply cannot figure this out.

Comment: Switch to a class… your app will need adjusting. A lot of you use SwiftUI but a

Comment: if the value for `repost` will be the same as the instance itself then you could do: `var repost: PostType? { self }`. Then you could just ignore the json for `repost`. Even if it's different I think a computed property might be your best bet if you don't want to adjust your app

Comment: @rayaantaneja if it was the same instance then there really would be no need for the property in the first place and why would it be optional, can you think of a situation when self both is nil and isn’t nil? ;)

Comment: As mentioned, switch to a class. There is nothing in your listed requirements that stops you from doing so

Comment: Can JSON be decoded into classes? If so, does it mean I have to change my JSON decoding at all?

Comment: There is no difference between a struct and a class for decoding json but why not try yourself.